# Wordpress custom meta box not saving all data

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, meta

I have the below code to add two separate meta boxes to my custom post type. Originally I had only the 'testimonial' meta box, which worked fine. I have now added 'credits' which is displaying fine in the admin, but doesn't seem to be saving to the database?

Can anyone help, hopefully it's nothing major.

```
// Allow registering of custom meta boxes
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_project_metaboxes' );

// Register the Project Meta Boxes
function add_project_metaboxes() {
    add_meta_box('oak_testimonial', 'Testimonial', 'oak_testimonial', 'project', 'normal', 'default');
    add_meta_box('oak_credits', 'Credits', 'oak_credits', 'project', 'side', 'default');
}

// Add Testimonial Metabox
function oak_testimonial() {
    global $post;

    // Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="testimonialmeta_noncename" id="testimonialmeta_noncename" value="' . 
    wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

    // Get the testimonial data if its already been entered
    $quote = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_quote', true);
    $name = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_name', true);
    $title = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_title', true);
    $company = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_company', true);

    // Echo out the field
    echo '<p>Name:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_name" value="' . $name  . '" class="widefat" />';
    echo '<p>Job Title:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_title" value="' . $title  . '" class="widefat" />';
    echo '<p>Company:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_company" value="' . $company  . '" class="widefat" />';
    echo '<p>Quote:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_quote" value="' . $quote  . '" class="widefat" />';

}

// Add Credits Metabox
function oak_credits() {
    global $post;

    // Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="creditsmeta_noncename" id="creditsmeta_noncename" value="' . 
    wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

    // Get the credits data if its already been entered
    $role1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_role1', true);
    $name1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_name1', true);
    $role2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_role2', true);
    $name2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_name2', true);
    $role3 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_role3', true);
    $name3 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_name3', true);

    // Echo out the field
    echo '<p>Role:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_name" value="' . $role1  . '" class="widefat" />';
    echo '<p>Name:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_title" value="' . $name1  . '" class="widefat" />';
    echo '<p>Role:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_name" value="' . $role2  . '" class="widefat" />';
    echo '<p>Name:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_title" value="' . $name2  . '" class="widefat" />';
    echo '<p>Role:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_name" value="' . $role3  . '" class="widefat" />';
    echo '<p>Name:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_title" value="' . $name3  . '" class="widefat" />';

}

// Save the Metabox Data
function oak_save_project_meta($post_id, $post) {

    // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
    // because save_post can be triggered at other times
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['testimonialmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
    return $post->ID;
    }
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['creditsmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
    return $post->ID;
    }

    // Is the user allowed to edit the post or page?
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
        return $post->ID;

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
    // We'll put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.

    $testimonial_meta['_quote'] = $_POST['_quote'];
    $testimonial_meta['_name'] = $_POST['_name'];
    $testimonial_meta['_title'] = $_POST['_title'];
    $testimonial_meta['_company'] = $_POST['_company'];

    $credit_meta['_role1'] = $_POST['_role1'];
    $credit_meta['_name1'] = $_POST['_name1'];
    $credit_meta['_role2'] = $_POST['_role2'];
    $credit_meta['_name2'] = $_POST['_name2'];
    $credit_meta['_role3'] = $_POST['_role3'];
    $credit_meta['_name3'] = $_POST['_name3'];

    // Add values of $testimonial_meta as custom fields
    foreach ($testimonial_meta as $key => $value) { // Cycle through the $testimonial_meta array
        if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; // Don't store custom data twice
        $value = implode(',', (array)$value); // If $value is an array, make it a CSV (unlikely)
        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { // If the custom field already has a value
            update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        } else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
            add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        }
        if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); // Delete if blank
    }

    // Add values of $credit_meta as custom fields
    foreach ($credit_meta as $key => $value) { // Cycle through the $testimonial_meta array
        if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; // Don't store custom data twice
        $value = implode(',', (array)$value); // If $value is an array, make it a CSV (unlikely)
        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { // If the custom field already has a value
            update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        } else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
            add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        }
        if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); // Delete if blank
    }

}

add_action('save_post', 'oak_save_project_meta', 1, 2); // save the custom fields
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "name" of your  of your 'oak_credits' metabox are wrong :

```
// Add Credits Metabox
function oak_credits() {
    global $post;

    // Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="creditsmeta_noncename" id="creditsmeta_noncename" value="' . 
    wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

    // Get the credits data if its already been entered
    $role1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_role1', true);
    $name1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_name1', true);
    $role2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_role2', true);
    $name2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_name2', true);
    $role3 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_role3', true);
    $name3 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_name3', true);

   // Echo out the field
    echo '<p>Role:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_role1" value="' . $role1  . '" class="widefat" />';
    echo '<p>Name:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_name1" value="' . $name1  . '" class="widefat" />';
    echo '<p>Role:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_role2" value="' . $role2  . '" class="widefat" />';
    echo '<p>Name:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_name2" value="' . $name2  . '" class="widefat" />';
    echo '<p>Role:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_role3" value="' . $role3  . '" class="widefat" />';
    echo '<p>Name:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_name3" value="' . $name3  . '" class="widefat" />';

}
```

Comment: Thank you, what a stupid mistake to make, looked at it for too long!

Comment: Might you know how to append punctuation (i.e ':') to the end of particular pieces of meta? Thanks